# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.(Tried every answer)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

**I tried every answer related to my question on this site and google but it did not resolve my question.**

I am trying to upload an image to my google bucket storage and get the download link.
I upload my image successfully. But the download link not working.

```
async uploadFiles(
    imageBuffer: Buffer,
    filename: string,
    imageData: string,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('mybucket.appspot.com');
    const fullPath = `${uuid()}-${filename}`;
    const bucketFile = bucket.file(fullPath);

    await bucketFile.save(imageBuffer, {
      contentType: file.mimetype,
      gzip: true,
    });

    const [url] = await bucketFile.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500',
      contentType: file.mimetype,
    });

    console.log(url);

    return url;
  }
```

This is my return URL value.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/ecoms-dev.appspot.com/83a50c9d-8811-4209-964b-ebc3aeeed642-Screenshot%202022-06-10%20201411.png?GoogleAccessId=firebase-adminsdk-qa8ey%40ecoms-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=16730303400&Signature=PAVEwBs5iLTg6WZ6A17IN3gBC%2FbKtYNQkBHi5y7QKHgppDDGXmTxs6C%2FVSeKi9Qg5vTDn926VkrrVlNiVlOVb1D3PLnPJv1QAV0uholTzpWLuu6hST7DVkMfiDQ0dSgeRWauw06fqcBfGBR9iIrmzAtqlRVHGiukus7mly7ZtLQrwAzfu51qeK%2BNnqpeZdarkUIJA35fj%2FWsohP36qkd4ljRmtU%2FfwbK5QBtiP2uQ5PZrvL8p8%2BQkVWeo%2Fcc37pXUARAWubXv428wVryPHtU%2FYUaT5%2BNpWROmhbOXL9CsYfIqBXSfZZMF%2FKUQ%2F1W%2F7GC7Oe4xzUmFGw7dLEjPVkHiQ%3D%3D
```

But when I tried to paste this url into my chrome... It returns an error like my topic.
Any idea about that. I am stuck with this error all day.

Comment: `but it did not resolve my question` ... maybe because you did not ask a question

Comment: Try reducing the expiration (e.g. to 15 minutes)

Comment: It would help if you include references to the libraries you're using too. You tagged the question `firebase-storage` but I think you're using the Cloud Storage library's [getSignedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest/storage/file#_google_cloud_storage_File_getSignedUrl_member_1_)

Comment: @DazWilkin I am using  firebase-admin

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution for my own answer.

```
const file = admin.storage().bucket("my bucket").file(`profile_photos/${uid}`);
await file.save(base64Image, {
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    },
    predefinedAcl: 'publicRead'
});
const metaData = await file.getMetadata()
const url = metaData[0].mediaLink
```

Comment: Please improve your answer to explain how this code fixes your problem.